# Custom calendar in android?

Tags: android, date, calendar

In my app i need this calendar with prices below it.Prices can be received from API 
But i want the numbers below dates in calendar?

I have date dialog picker in my app but i need to show numbers below dates.How can i do that?

But i want the numbers below dates in calendar?

[image: ScreenShot of calendar]

Comment: What have u tried till now ?

Comment: @Raj i have date dialog picker in my app but i need to show numbers below dates.How can i do that?

Comment: Down voter should put reason for downvoting in comment. So i could improve my question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no code for you because it's very large.

You should custom a calendar for you, or using library, my suggestion is 
[this library](https://github.com/badoualy/datepicker-timeline?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5965)

Hope it can helps you.

Comment: @GiahTran Thanks it helped :)